# How to present a monitor implementation of a counting semaphore without busy waiting?

Tags: c, operating-system

I am currently studying the OS. This question is for my mid-term.

present a monitor implementation of a counting semaphore. Apart from
initialization, the monitor implements two enyprocedures P() and V(). Indicate clearly the regular
variables used and the condition variables used. Do not neglect to present how the ordinary variables
are initialized. Reminder: busy waiting inside the monitor is not allowed.

I know what monitor and counting semaphore are. Specifically, I understand what Peterson and Dekker algorithms are. However, I think both of them will cause busy waiting. Is there any way to solve it? Or, I misunderstand the question because my English is poor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right in that both the algorithms do busy waiting. But they do busy waiting ***outside*** the monitor. Your question asks you not to busy wait ***inside*** the monitor.

*Side note*: While busy waiting might seem a bad idea, it is very important to systems that need to avoid latency. In such cases, busy waiting is the best way to go and the programmers will have thorough understanding of the platform before they implement busy waiting.

Comment: 'In such cases, busy waiting is the best way to go' well, considering that busy-waiting uses up a core and wastes memory-bandwidth, you have to be very careful when making such broad statements.  Busy-waiting makes sense in only a narrow set of conditions.

Comment: @MartinJames That's true! I was referring to those narrow set of unavoidable conditions.